# Looping index number in descending order using mathimatical expression

Tags: loops, math

I have a button, when I click on it, my program shows number between 0 and n (excluding n itself) in ascending order. Example: if `n = 5` then when I press button it shows `0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 ...` and so on.
Mathematically I can write it like `(i+1) mod n`, where i previous number.
Is there mathematical expression to show numbers in descending order?

```
Ex.: 0 4 3 2 1 0 4 3 2 1 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing descending order, presumably you want to start with 4 in your example, not 0.  Then you can do `i-1 mod n` mathematically.  Depending on the language you're using that may or may not work with the native "mod" operator since some are signed and some are not.  You didn't specify a language, though, just the math.

Comment: Actually, as I look at it again, the expression is right no matter where you want to start.  That's just a question of where you start `i` at the beginning of your loop.

Comment: if i = 0, then (0-1) mod 5 = 1, but it must be 4.

Comment: No, `-1 mod 5 = 4`. See, for example, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1+mod+5

Answer (score 0):

For a descending order, if you don't want a regressive counter, use the mathematical expression:

```
n-(i mod n) - 1
```

If you need a 0 as the first result, use:

```
((n-(i mod n)-1) + 1) mod n
```

Comment: if n = 3 and i = 2, 3 - (2 mod 3) - 1 = 0, but must be 1

Comment: yes, but in my first formula, I not use 0 as first term. Please, check the second formula: ((n-(i mod n)-1) + 1) mod n